# PCL installation error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I followed this [blog](https://larrylisky.com/2014/03/03/installing-pcl-on-ubuntu/) to install PCL and its dependencies in Ubuntu 16.04 version.

For the command

```
sudo apt-get install libvtk5.8-qt4 libvtk5.8 libvtk5-dev
```

I was getting an error, so I installed

```
sudo apt-get install libvtk5-qt4-dev libvtk6.2 libvtk5-dev
```

Now after executing the `make` command , I am getting an error like this:

```
>/usr/include/vtk-5.10/QVTKWidget.h:40:25: fatal error: QtGui/QWidget: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
apps/CMakeFiles/pcl_pcd_video_player.dir/build.make:70: recipe for target 'apps/CMakeFiles/pcl_pcd_video_player.dir/include/pcl/apps/moc_pcd_video_player.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [apps/CMakeFiles/pcl_pcd_video_player.dir/include/pcl/apps/moc_pcd_video_player.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8401: recipe for target 'apps/CMakeFiles/pcl_pcd_video_player.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/CMakeFiles/pcl_pcd_video_player.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you fix it. I'm having a similar issue now.

Comment: I think you need to remove your first version, and then reinstall the next one, with a purge command